# Loading data through scrolldown

Tags: php, html

i have a web page that shows tabular data,
 and i would like to know how to load the data through scrolling down, facebook style.
Like, loading 50 rows, and when you scroll to the end,   load 50 more.
I don't know how to specify the question, or else i would have searched for a question with an   answer "there is probably already somewhere", but i don't know if i have to use php,     javascript or what. Can annione give me any pointers on the subject?
This is the page in question:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function test(id)
        {
            window.open("../remover/removeemail.php?id=" +     id,'Favourites','menubar,resizable,width=400,height=200');
        }
        function test2(id)
        {
            window.location = ("../editar/editaemail.php?id=" + id);
        }
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("problema na conexao");
mysql_select_db("trabalho1");
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM email";
    $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                foreach ($row as $campo=>$valor) {
                    if($campo=="COUNT(id)") 
                    {
                    $maxemail = $valor;
                    }                   
                                             }                          
                                                        }                   
$query = "SELECT * FROM email GROUP BY id ORDER BY nome";
$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());   
            echo"<center>";
            echo "<table border='2'>\n";
            echo"<form>";
            echo"<tr><td colspan='3'>Numero de Emails Registrados: ".$maxemail. "</td><td colspan='3'><a align='left' href='../filtrar/filtroemail.php'>Filtrar Resultados</a>        <a align='right' href='../inserir/inseriremail.html'>Adicionar Email</a></td</tr>";
            echo "<tr align='center'><td>Data de Criação</td><td>Nome</td><td>Email</td><td>Data da ultima Actualização</td><td>Remover</td><td>Actualizar</td></tr>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {    

                                echo "<tr align='center'>\n";
                                echo "<td><b></b>".$row['datahora']. "</td>";       

                                echo "<td><b></b>".$row['nome']. "</td>";

                                echo "<td><b></b>".$row['email']. "</td>";

                                echo "<td><b></b>".$row['dataactual']. "</td>";


                                echo "<td><input name='eliminar' type='button' onClick='test(".$row['id'].")' value='Remover'></td>";
                                echo "<td><input name='editar' type='button' onClick='test2(".$row['id'].")' value='Actualizar'></td>";


                echo "</form>\n";
                                                            }
                echo "</table>\n";
                echo"</center>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use both javascript and php.

I'll only give you some pointers because you said you can't use libraries.

- Create a div containing the table
- Give the div a fixed height and set it scrollable vertically (css)
- Bind a listener to the onscroll event (javascript)
- In the listener you check if the scroll reached the bottom and if so, you should make an ajax call to a php file (javascript makes a call to a php file and get result back without reloading the page)
- Consult the database and return data (php)
- Add the new data in the table (javascript)

Ajax calls are VERY EASY to implement with jQuery but more difficult (if cross-browser) without it.

You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP).

If you need more pointers on this, comment my answer and I will insert more informations in it.

Comment: Just read your answer, thanks alot. I will check it out today, if i need help i'll call. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin like JQuery Infinite scroll.

[Infinite scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

Here's a demo.

[Infinite scroll demo](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/infinite-scrolling-demo1/)

Comment: Thanks, but can you also tell me an alternative that would depend on simply coding? It's for a project im doing for school, and i guess the more we do ourselves and the less we depend on plugins the better.
Anyway, i'l mark your answer as accepted since it did answer my question. But can you tell me about something else? Through coding it myself preferably

Comment: @Heatmanofurioso  I agree that the more control you have over your code the better your off. But there is no point of reinventing the wheel. You can use this plugin safely. I've used it in many of my own projects. Its flexible and can be extended easily.

Comment: True. Thankyou very much then!
I'l accept your answer in 5 mins